# Is /etc/services actively used when an application binds to a port?

Tags: networking, configuration, services, etc

When an application is looking for a port to bind to,
is `/etc/services` actively searched to ensure there are no clashes? 
I.e., if a port is registered in `/etc/services`,
is it reserved whether it’s actually in use or not?

Comment: I find this question somewhat confusing.  Are you talking about servers or clients (or both)?  What do you mean by “clashes”, “reserved” and “in use”? … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: To use `/etc/services` is mandarory with `inetd.conf`. In every other contexts you can use port numbers

Answer (score 2):

Each TCP connection involves not one but *two* port numbers: a local port and a remote port. On an outgoing connection, the local port number is not important, and most programs let the operating system pick it. As noted by binarysta, the OS will then automatically pick the first free port in the Ephemeral Port Range.

But the application (or the user running the application) must specify the remote port number to connect to, or else it will not reach the correct service in the remote host.

On incoming connections, the situation is mirrored: a server application normally cannot let the OS choose the number for a local port used to listen for incoming connections, or else the clients would not know which port to connect to. But an application listening for incoming connections will normally ignore the remote port number and let it be decided by the remote host.

(There are some services that use fully dynamic port numbers and usually rely on secondary discovery protocols to find out which port(s) the server is listening in: NFSv3 `rpc.statd` and `rpc.mountd` are perhaps the most familiar examples for modern Linux users. To find them on the remote host, you're supposed to first contact the RPC portmapper on port 111 on that host and ask which ports the services are in.)

Some server applications (mostly classic Unix server applications such as `inetd`) might look up local ports to use by name, using `getportbyname()` which normally simply looks it up from `/etc/services`.

But an application is free to skip this step, and instead directly specify the desired port by number. Most modern applications tend to do it this way; certainly any server program that requires you to configure a listening port by number does it this way.

On these days, the more common use of `/etc/services` might be by applications like `lsof`, `netstat` or `tcpdump`, which may replace port numbers in their output with more human-friendly names looked up from `/etc/services`. But you should keep in mind that such port number-to-name lookup can only be relied on to describe *typical use*: it may or may not be an accurate description of a port's *actual use* on your specific system.

So for the question "if a port is registered in `/etc/services`, is it reserved?" the answer is **no, it isn't**.

*Some* applications may use `/etc/services` to determine the port numbers to use, unless the port number is directly specified in the application configuration, or by the user.

Protection against "clashes" happens at the OS level, completely unrelated to `/etc/services`: if an application makes a `bind(2)` system call to specify that it wants to use a particular port number, and that port is already in use by something else, the system call will fail with an `EADDRINUSE` error, to indicate that something else is already using it.

Comment: Each TCP connection involves not one but two port numbers: the port number on the ***client*** socket (which initiates the connection) and the port number on the ***server*** socket (which receives the connection).  The sockets can be on the same machine.   IMO, it’s misleading to talk about local ports and remote ports without at least mentioning that it’s the relationship between them that’s important, and not their locations.

Comment: Still, on the viewpoint of an application, one is "local" (= directly controlled by the application) and the other is "remote" (= controlled by something else). For example, when looking at `netstat` output, the endpoints (IP:port pairs) are not labeled in "client" and "server" terms, but as "local" and "foreign".  But that was just an introduction for talking about `/etc/services` and its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

No, the applications request bind to a port but actually it's the operating system that decides to assign a port to an application or not.

so for example ports less than 1024 only can be used by `root` or any user with `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.

`proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` defines the local port range that is used by TCP & UDP traffic to choose the local port, it's called  Ephemeral Port Range (you can change it)

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

32768   60999
```

or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

Also some ports can be reserved by administrator with configuring `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports` or the kernel parameter`net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports`, so these ports will not be used by automatic port assignments.

The purpose of `/etc/services` is so that programs can do `getportbyname()` sockets call in their code in order to get the port they should use.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you might have misunderstood the question.  Then you edited your answer again, and now I believe that you’ve contradicted yourself. If the operating system assigns ports to applications, why do programs need to “get the port they should use”?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica applications request the port from OS, but OS decides to assign or not based on many parameters (permissions, port availability,...) maybe I have not described clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Many applications have something known as a [well known port number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). They will usually bind to it.

Other applications will bind to port 0, letting the system choose a free port. Then they communicate their port numbers to eventual clients using other methods (other than well known port numbers). For example broadcasting their availability to the network.

Answer (score 0):

So much to digest. I think I have the answer I need:
/etc/services is merely a register of well-known services and official names. It might be directly referenced  using getportbyname() but it’s not obligatory.
When a dynamic port is request probably for an outgoing port. ip_local_port_range is reference as to allowed port range
Some ports can be reserved by the admin by adding them to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports or the kernel parameter rnet.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports. These ports will not be used by automatic port assignments.
If I have this correct, the reason I asked the question is I have moved from my safe on-prem world of AIX into the wild to the Azure Cloud and SUSE. For clusters in the cloud they use a Load Balancer function to define, amongst other things, the service IP address that will move between the nodes of a cluster. They have to be given a specific port to use and that was chosen as 62500 for example. I recently have been testing some backup software called Commvault and very occasionally it grabs the same port before the cluster is started so I have been looking for ways to stop that. It appears I have either to change the default local port range so the high mark is 62499  or add the port specifically into ip_local_reserved_ports
If I have got all this correct thank you all for very much for your swift help,